# HTML link for bottom and top page

Tags: html

I want to put a link in my page which will take me to the bottom of the page and a link which will take me to the top of my page, and also to some section of the page.
How can I put a link to my page that will not redirect me to another website but to the top/bottom of the page or a section?

Thanks

Comment: You can link to specific elements by their ID. i.e. `<div id="section"></div>` and `<a href="#section">Go</a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use a html anchor.

For example, at the top of your page (actually where you want to point to), one of the html element has the id `top`.

```
<div id="top"> ...</div>
```

If you put a link such as:

```
<a href="#top">go to the top</a>
```

...on click the browser will point to the div with id `top`.
It goes the same way for any part of your page.

Comment: Adding to this. Having a scroll effect otherwise it will simply jump to the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

For this you'll need **anchor links** Like so:

```
<a href="#bottom">bottom section</a>
```

followed by an element at the bottom of your **HTML** page with the `id="bottom"`